# Pass shortcut arguments in .bat (batch)

Tags: windows, batch-file

In a .exe shortcut, I can use extra arguments. But how to pass those arguments in a .bat file?

Comment: Some more details? What exactly you mean by pass arguments in a bat file?

Comment: In a shortcut you can add a parameter, for example, a custom resolution. I want to use this parameter in a .bat file, because a .bat file uses only .exe(s) and not shortcuts.

Comment: Ah, I see. You just want to replace shortcut with command line script.

Comment: Yeap, exactly this!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To pass argument to bat or cmd file - you just run script with parameters, like this:

```
script.cmd parameter1 parameter2
```

Inside script - if you pass arguments - you will have %1 %2 %3 special variables available, and you can use them like this

```
echo First argument is %1
echo Second argument is %2

echo Starting application with arguments
application.exe %1 %2
```

More information:

[Windows batch scripting / Command line arguments at Wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Batch_Scripting#Command-line_arguments)

**EDIT / added later after discussion in comments.**

To replace shortcut with command line file (cmd or bat) - create `.bat` or `.cmd` file like this:

```
"C:\Some Location\Some application.exe" argument1 argument2
```

Comment: the .bat goes like this:

first.exe second.exe

and I want to add "-vidmode 1440,900,60" (without quotes).

I tried it but it doesnt work. I dont know if the scpaces are the cause. In the shotcut it would be 

"C:\folder\1.exe" -vidmode 1440,900,60

Comment: Is there a way to grab ALL the args passed, so they can ALL be passed to i.e. `application.exe` (in python the syntax would be *args in the function arg list)?

Answer (score 4):

In exactly the same way:

```
BatchFile.bat param1 param2 ...
```

Inside the batch file the parameters are addressed as `%1`, `%2`, ...